# Why does background-origin not work in the body

Tags: css

Background-origin is tested successfully in div, but not in body
https://chestnuttree.github.io/helloWord/pic1.png

Then I found out that the background-origin of body works by adding a background color to the body's parent element, HTML
https://chestnuttree.github.io/helloWord/pic2.png

```css
body {
  padding: 10px;
  background: url(/i/eg_bg_03.gif) no-repeat #58a bottom right;
  background-origin: content-box;
}

html {
  background: #fff;
}
```

Why is that ?

Comment: Just curious what do you need `background-origin` for? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Seno: I found this problem when I was learning some related properties of CSS and practicing the demo, but I didn't find the reason. I was a little curious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The background applied to body element is special because it will get propagated to html then the canvas:

> For documents whose root element is an HTML HTML element or an XHTML html element [HTML]: if the computed value of background-image on the root element is none and its background-color is transparent, user agents **must instead propagate the computed values of the background properties** from that element’s first HTML BODY or XHTML body child element. The used values of that BODY element’s background properties are their initial values, and the propagated values are treated as if they were specified on the root element. It is recommended that authors of HTML documents specify the canvas background for the BODY element rather than the HTML element. <sup>[red](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#special-backgrounds)</sup>

In the example below, I am applying background to body but in reality these properties are applied to html so padding has no effect in calculating the origin.

```css
body {
  padding: 10px;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/10/50/50) no-repeat #58a bottom right;
  background-origin: content-box;
  margin:0;
  height:100vh;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Add padding to the html instead and the `background-origin` will work:

```css
body {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/10/50/50) no-repeat #58a bottom right;
  background-origin: content-box;
  margin:0;
  height:100%;
  padding:10px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

html {
  padding:10px;
  height:100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Or apply a background to html different from `transparent` and you will stop the propagation:

```css
body {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/10/50/50) no-repeat #58a bottom right;
  background-origin: content-box;
  margin:0;
  height:100%;
  padding:10px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

html {
  padding:10px;
  height:100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  background:red;
}
```